# Getting the error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring'", how do I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

After installing react-instagram-embed package I got this error and tried all possible solution but still not working!!! Anyone knows solution for this??

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in
> 'C:\Users\vytck\Desktop\ibm\node_modules\finnhub\dist'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
> - install 'querystring-es3' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: {
>   "querystring": false }

Answer (score 8):

`querystring` is deprecated since at least since last **Node LTS version 14**.

So if you want to keep your current version of react-instagram-embed

install querystring-es3

`yarn add querystring-es3` or `npm i querystring-es3`

in your **webpack.config.js** configuration file update or add the resolve entry to look like this

```
resolve: {
   fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

querystring can be directly introduced using 'qs' in the new version of node

```
import qs from 'qs'
```