# Can't resolve 'querystring' in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Has anyone know how to solve this because , i tried todo as error message said, it didint work

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in
> 'C:\Users\vytck\Desktop\ibm\node_modules\finnhub\dist'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
> - install 'querystring-es3' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: {
>   "querystring": false }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/Users/apple/Documents/mern-instagram/instagram-clone/node\_modules/react-instagram-embed/es'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640271/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-querystring-in-users-apple-documents)

Answer (score 1):

in `your-project/node_modules/react-scripts/config`
open file `webpack.config.js` 
command+F '**fallback**' or '**resolve: {**'
there inside `resolve` object add:

```
fallback: { 
        "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") ,
        "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/"),
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "url": require.resolve("url/"),
        "util": require.resolve("util/"),
},
```

then run `npm i querystring-es3 path-browserify buffer crypto-browserify stream-http stream-browserify url util`
that is all you lack in webpack > 5
or you can just add the ones you need
*happy coding!*

Comment: how can this work on a server when you run a build???

Answer (score 0):

querystring is deprecated since last few node lts versions

install querystring-es3 by below command

```
npm i querystring-es3
```

in your webpack.config.js configuration file update or add the resolve entry to look like this

```
resolve: {
   fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }
}
```

Comment: How do I do this in create React App where I don't have a webpack config?

Comment: This worked in my case where I needed to require my api client library as created by swagger-codegen within a project that isn't react but uses webpack v5.